# Azure DevOps (TFS) in Safari keeps asking password

Tags: macos, safari

After upgrading to macOS Monterey, Safari keeps showing authentication prompts for the on-premises Azure DevOps instance. Interesting that I can keep pressing the cancel button on the login form, and it allows me to view the site.

It works from macOS Big Sur & Safari Version 14.1.2 (16611.3.10.1.6).
In macOS Monterey, it works in other browsers (Microsoft Edge, Chrome), all works fine. I enter login/password one time and it never asks me again.

In the browser tab, I see that the /connect request got stuck, but I don't know how to troubleshoot it further. Any suggestions?

Environment information:

- **macOS version:** 12.0.1
- **Safari version:** 15.1
- Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This currently seems to be a bug with the new NSUrlSession Websocket implementation in WebKit.

You can read more about it here:

https://github.com/wandenberg/nginx-push-stream-module/issues/295

Until either Microsoft fixes it on their end or Apple fixes it on their end (depending on how you look at a possible resolution) you can disable the NSURLSession Websocket Experimental Feature to fix the multiple prompts showing up and the /connect call to work properly:

On iOS:

Go to Settings App -> Safari -> Advanced -> Experimental Features -> NSURLSession WebSocket and disable it.

On macOS:

Open Safari, go to Preferences, click on Advanced,  check the box to "Show Develop menu in toolbar", close Preferences, click on Develop -> Experimental Features, and scroll to "NSURLSession WebSocket" and uncheck it.

This will revert to the previous websocket implementation that does not have this issue.

Comment: According to the link you posted, this issue has been fixed

Comment: This doesn't work for Safari 17.

Answer (score 0):

I use Edge and Firefox browsers with Microsoft developed web apps (O365 / Azure and other admin portals). For me, the path of least resistance works since they don’t test well with Safari and many things are often broken even after you get logged in. I don’t want to be their QA and ticket generator anymore after speaking with our TAM / account rep and engineering team a few times.